# In pst-circ, how do you rotate the op-amp by 90 degrees?

Tags: pstricks, pst-circ

In `pst-circ`, how can you rotate the `op-amp` by 90 degrees?

For items that have two terminals like resistors and inductors, they rotate automatically.  For the 3 terminal `op-amp` I'm having trouble.

I'm currently using PCTeX v5 and `pst-circ` v1.2a in WinXP.

I tried....

```
\OA[OAperfect = false]{90}(A1c)(A1a)(A1b)
```

but that did not work.

Also I gave this a shot...

```
\OA[OAperfect = false,TRot= 90](A1c)(A1a)(A1b)
```

but I think `TRot` is only for transistors.

This is what I have now

[image: What I get]

from this code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(8,12)

\pnode(10,7.75){A1a} \pnode(13,8){A1b} \pnode(10,8.25){A1c}
\pnode(1,4){R7a} \pnode(3,4){R7b}  
\pnode(4,4){R8a} \pnode(6,4){R8b} 
\pnode(7,4){R9a} \pnode(9,4){R9b} 
\pnode(10,4){Ca} \pnode(11,4){Cb}


\resistor[ dipolestyle= zigzag](R7a)(R7b){$R_7$}
\resistor[ dipolestyle= zigzag](R8a)(R8b){$R_8$}
\resistor[ dipolestyle= zigzag](R9a)(R9b){$R_9$}
\capacitor(Ca)(Cb){$C$}
\wire(R7b)(R8a)
\wire(R8b)(R9a)
\wire(R9b)(Ca)
\wire(Cb)(12,4)

\OA[OAperfect = false](A1c)(A1a)(A1b)

\wire(A1b)(13,10)
\wire(13,10)(3.5,10)
\wire(3.5,10)(3.5,4)

\wire(A1c)(6.5,8.25)
\wire(6.5,8.25)(6.5,4)

\wire(A1a)(9.5,7.75)
\wire(9.5,7.75)(9.5,4)


\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

What I would like is this...

[image: What I want]
which I made using `circuitikz`

Comment: Can you show what you have tried, so that someone may try to replicate your problem and (possibly) solve it.

Comment: Based on the [`pstricks` mailing list](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2012/009478.html), it seems like you have a *very* outdated version of [`pst-circ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) - 1.2a. The most recent version is 2.02. Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows your code, as well as the output in the form of an image.

Comment: I edited the post based on your suggestions, still looking for a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @ori333: I think the easiest way is to draw the tripole by hand.